# What is the origin of "den Bogen raus haben"?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Metaphorically, this phrase means something like "getting the hang of". But what is "Bogen" referring to, literally, in this case?

(Come to think of it, I have no idea what "getting the hang of it" means literally either - a bit of quick research shows a few possible different origins - one relating to muskets, another to public executions/hangings)

Comment: Nur geraten: Dass man sich bei einem neuen Bogen (der Waffe) erst einschießen muss um zu wissen, wie stark man ihn spannen muss, insbesondere für Einzelstücke aus historischer Handarbeit, weniger für moderne Sportgeräte. Weniger wahrscheinlich scheint mir eine Herkunft aus der Musik (Geigenbogen) oder dem Motorsport/Skisport - wo man ja auch eher von Kurven spricht als von Bögen.

Comment: "umgangssprachlich; [Die Herkunft der Redensart ist unklar](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~den%20Bogen%20/%20richtigen%20Dreh%20raushaben%20/%20heraushaben&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou). Da "Bogen" auch "das Krumme" bedeutet, könnte an die Geschicklichkeit bei der Herstellung "gerader" Dinge (etwa aus Eisen) gedacht werden. Das "Krumme rausmachen" würde dann bedeuten: geschickt sein "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is very little information on the etymology of this proverb. Other than we think at first sight it appears not to be related to the bow in archery but together with other proverbs comes from the textile industry. There it was attributed to the manual skill of **weavers** or **spinners**.

> - Dann werden die Fäden am Webstuhl verarbeitet, falls die Weberin „gut in Schuss“ ist und sie **„den Bogen raus“** hat.<sup>[Beeker Flachsmuseum](http://www.heimatverein-beeck.de/index_flachsmuseum.htm)</sup>
> - In der deutschen Sprache gibt es viele Redewendungen aus der Textilbranche: „spindeldürr“, „jemand spinnt“, „den Faden verlieren“ oder **„den Bogen raus haben“**.<sup>[Bamberger Online-Zeitung](http://www.bamberger-onlinezeitung.de/2012/05/12/wie-am-seidenen-faden/)</sup>
> - „Etwas anzetteln“, „sich verzetteln“, „jemandem etwas andrehen“ oder **„den Bogen raus haben“** kommt von dem Zusammenfügen der Spinnfäden. Der Begriff „Der alte Knacker“ stammt vom Zählwerk der Spinnhaspel.<sup>[Augsburger Allgemeine](http://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/noerdlingen/Woher-kommt-der-alte-Knacker-id21406156.html)</sup>

When we look further at old publications on the art of spinnning we can find the following interesting notes where a bow may have played a role:

---

> - [image]
> - Ein sanfteres, gelinderes, und unverderblicheres Mittel, für diese zarte, feine, weiche Seide, ist der Schnarr**bogen** oder das Fachen, so wie die Huthmacher die feinen kurzen Haare verarbeiten<sup>[Neues Hannoverisches Magazin](http://books.google.de/books?id=_uoWAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PT122&ots=asoEJbRb2M&dq=bogen%20fachen%20spinnen&pg=PT122#v=onepage&q=bogen%20fachen%20spinnen&f=false)</sup>

---

> - [image]
> - Nahe diesem hohlen Cylinder sind 2 Flügel von Holz oder Eisen, in Gestalt eines **Bogens** oder rechten Winkels angebracht, welche den Umschwung der Spindel befördern.<sup>[Encyclopädisches Werk der Wissenschaften, Künste und Gewerbe 21](http://books.google.de/books?id=x4JMAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA619&ots=0FGK-SQR5u&dq=schnurr%20bogen%20spinnen&pg=PA619#v=onepage&q=schnurr%20bogen%20spinnen&f=false)</sup>

Comment: Die Stoffballen der Weber und Spinner sollten ja schön rechteckig sein. Dazu wurden sie in rechteckigen Gestellen hergestellt. Wenn man sie dann aber aus den Gestellen herausnahm, verzogen sie sich unter umständen aufgrund verschiedener Zugspannungen in den einzelnen Zeilen. Dadurch wurden die Seiten gebogen. Ein Lehrling, bei dem das nicht mehr auftrat „hatte den Bogen raus“.

Answer (score 0):

I have not verified how old the saying "den Bogen raushaben" is. Maybe the origin is connected with weaving. My association was always skiing. A beginner has to learn how to manage to go into a curve. When he knows how to do it then he might say: Jetzt hab ich den Bogen raus meaning Ich habe herausgekriegt, wie man einen Bogen fährt. But I would consider this explanation not as a historical explanation, but only as a plausibility explanation that is finding a situation where the saying might make sense.
Often there are historical explanations but they are difficult to verify or they do not convince. Then a plausibility explanation at least helps to understand the saying.

At any case I would not think of a weapon as a bow in the pocket. You wear a bow on your back and if need be you take it off your back, but not out of your pocket. That is an association that may be helpful for someone but the image in not correct in details.

Answer (score -1):

-Den Bogen raus haben-, I would think it is -having the bow out of its pocket, drawing the bow out of ist Holster, like with a sword, if you where able to draw it, you would be able to use it. In that sense, if I was able to get the bow -den Bogen- into Action, I wouldnt be boethered with it not being useful to me.

Comment: This is unfounded speculation, right?